# how do i play an animation after colliding with a gameobject for x seconds in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was wondering how to play an animation after a certain amount of seconds but only if its been colliding with something, if it wasn't colliding anymore it would reset the seconds until it collides with the other object again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. It sounds to me like what you want is

- Check if your object collides
- Start a timer / countdown
- If the timer finishes do something like play your animation
- If the collision ends cancel the timer (if still running)

You could use e.g.

```c#
// The delay to wait before triggering the animation
// Adjust via the Inspector
public float delay = 3;

// Holds the currently running countdown routine
private Coroutine _currentRoutine;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //ToDo: Eventually filter the collisions

    // Is the routine already running? -> do nothing
    if(_currentRoutine != null) return;
    
    // Start a new routine
    _currentRoutine  = StartCoroutine(PlayAnimationAfterDelay());
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    //ToDo: Eventually filter the collisions the same way as in enter

    // Is there still a routine running? -> cancel it
    if(_currentRoutine != null) StopCoroutine(_currentRoutine);
}

private IEnumerator PlayAnimationAfterDelay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

    //Todo: Whatever you need to do to play the animation

    // Never sure if this is needed but just to be sure reset when finished
    _currentRoutine = null;
}
```

See

- [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)
- [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) / [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)
- [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) / [`OnCollisionExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html)
- [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Comment: thanks this looks like exactly what i wanted! I'll test out a script based off of this as soon as I get home.